# Intersection of N sets

Tags: javascript

Mozilla has [an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Iterating_Sets) showing how to intersect two sets like so:

```
var intersection = new Set([...set1].filter(x => set2.has(x)));
```

but what's the most concise (compact) way to intersect N sets? Thanks.

Comment: By "best", what are you looking for exactly? Most efficient? Simplest? Most concise?

Comment: @Bergi Actually I was hoping to get a few different options depending on people's opinions. But you're right, I'm not being clear. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take this approach and reduce an array of sets.

```js
var set1 = new Set([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]),
    set2 = new Set([1, 4, 5, 7, 9]),
    set3 = new Set([1, 4, 5, 8, 9]),
    intersection = [set1, set2, set3].reduce((a, b) => new Set([...a].filter(x => b.has(x))));

console.log([...intersection]);
```

Same with using a prototype and `thisArg` for filtering.

```js
var set1 = new Set([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]),
    set2 = new Set([1, 4, 5, 7, 9]),
    set3 = new Set([1, 4, 5, 8, 9]),
    intersection = [set1, set2, set3].reduce((a, b) => 
        new Set([...a].filter(Set.prototype.has, b)));

console.log([...intersection]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Found in [an old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31931030/1048572), I recommend this:

```
function intersect(...sets) {
    if (!sets.length) return new Set();
    const i = sets.reduce((m, s, i) => s.size < sets[m].size ? i : m, 0);
    const [smallest] = sets.splice(i, 1);
    const res = new Set();
    for (let val of smallest)
        if (sets.every(s => s.has(val)))
             res.add(val);
    return res;
}
```

It's both elegant and efficient :-) Its time complexity is linear to the size of the smallest input set and linear to the number of sets, and it doesn't construct any unnecessary temporary arrays on the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, getting the first set of one array of sets, and then filter this one by those elements that belongs to all the other sets:

```js
let sets = [
    new Set([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]),
    new Set([1, 4, 5, 7, 9]),
    new Set([1, 4, 5, 8, 9])
];

// Generate the intersection.
let intersection = new Set([...sets[0]].filter(
    x => sets.slice(1).every(s => s.has(x))
));

console.log([...intersection]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```