# Expect tests don't work with the ES6 / ES2015 Set object

Tags: javascript, node.js, set, babeljs

## Issue

The test below should fail, but it is passing:

```
it('should fail', () => {
  const actual = new Set('a');
  const expected = new Set('b');
  expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
});
```

[image]

## Background & Question

I'm using [the `expect` package from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect). I'm using Babel 5 to use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). I'm using Node 5, so the Set being used [should be native](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/).
Am I doing something wrong, or does this look like a bug in the `expect` package in the way it handles Sets? I've cross posted an issue on the package as I'm not sure.

Comment: You could try hapijs [code](https://github.com/hapijs/code) instead of expect for assertions, I just tested the assertion and it worked

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128855/comparing-ecma6-sets-for-equality

Answer (score 2):

## 1. This is "expected behavior"

`expect` depends on `deep-equal`, which does not support sets and maps.

This in consistent with the behavior of node's `assert` :

```
var a = new Set('a');
var b = new Set('b');
console.log(require('assert').deepEqual(a, b) || 'ok');
// Prints 'ok' !
```

This issue has been discussed here :

[assert: add support for Set and Map](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/2315)

This comment is particularly interesting :

> I don't think we should do this (or anything else in #2309). Assert should remain used only for testing io.js itself, and not try to be a good general assertion library. If io.js tests need this ability enough times that we need to factor it out, we should, but until then, just adding it because it'd be nice isn't a good idea IMO.

## 2. Workaround

You can either:

- use [assert6](https://github.com/evanlucas/assert6)
- or (re)open the tickets to raise concern about this
- or use another library, like [code](https://github.com/hapijs/code) that @simon-p-r mentioned
- or do the comparison manually. See [Comparing ECMA6 sets for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128855/comparing-ecma6-sets-for-equality)