# How to find existence of an array in a set?

Tags: javascript, set

Since set in Javascript is able to take object, including arrays, how do I find the existence of an array list in a set?

I tried the following code:

```
var sello = new Set();
sello.add(["a","b"])
console.log(sello.has(["a","b"])) // outputs false
```

I'm assuming

`sello.has(["a","b"])`

should have output true since I've added the exact array in the set `sello`. Am I missing out some falsy truthy thing or any logical error?

Note:

- I'm not looking to match only the character `"a"` and/or `"b"`, I'm
  looking to match the whole array `["a","b"]`.
- I'm looking to match the array. I just need the content to be the
  same, the elements doesn't have to be the same order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing ECMA6 sets for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128855/comparing-ecma6-sets-for-equality)

Comment: @imjared that was comparing 2 sets, I'm looking to find something within a set. More arrays could be insert in the set. I just didn't write that out. Didn't think it was necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do won't work because in Javascript you can't compare arrays like that, even if they have the same values.  This is because arrays are reference types, not value types, and for reference types Javascript determines whether they are equal or not based on whether they are referencing the same object (i.e. the same place in memory).  For instance, just try:

```
console.log(['a','b'] == ['a','b']); // false
```

Despite having the same values, each array is a new reference, so they are not equal to each other.

In contrast, the comparison in the code below does involve arrays referencing the same object on both sides of the equation:

```
let a = ['a','b'];
console.log(a == a); // true
```

And therefore:

```
let sello = new Set();
sello.add(a);
console.log(sello.has(a)); // true
```

To remedy this, you'll want to create a function that compares arrays based on their values.  You can first check if the arrays have the same length.  If not, then they're not equal.  You can then loop through the items in each and see if any are different for any given position.  If so, they're not equal.  Otherwise, assuming you're dealing with a flat array of primitive values (no nested objects of reference type), then the arrays are equal.  This is what I do in 'isEqual' below:

```
function isEqual(x,y) {
    if (x.length != y.length)
        return false;
    for (let i in x)
        if (x[i] != y[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Test it if you like:

```
console.log(isEqual(['a','b'],['a','b'])); // true
```

Now, unfortunately, `Set.has()` doesn't accept a function, so we can't use it with `isEqual`.  But you can just loop through the values of the set.  If creating a one-liner is the goal, the best way I have found to do this is to convert the set to an array and use the `some` method.  `some` accepts a function that evaluates each row, and if it returns true for any row, then the result is true, else false.

```
console.log(
    [...sello].some(item => isEqual(item, ['a','b']))
); 
// true
```

Comment: I added an edit to bold that one line that helps me to understand and cleared my confusion. I hope you don't mind. =) And thank you!

Comment: @ccsalison, go ahead and try the edit again, as far as I can tell he didn't seem to have gone through.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, Arrays are Objects, and no two **separate Objects** are ever considered equal.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) shows the same error with a standard object:

```
var set1 = new Set();
var obj1 = {'key1': 1};
set1.add(obj1);

set1.has(obj1);        // returns true
set1.has({'key1': 1}); // returns false because they are different object references
```

---

The easiest way to use `.has` with an Object (such as an Array) is to get a **reference** to the Object, like:

```js
let sello = new Set();
let myArray = ["a","b"];
sello.add(myArray);

console.log(sello.has(myArray)); // outputs true
```

---

**If you can't** get a reference to the Array, you'll probably need to check each Array in the Set by iterating through the Array and comparing each element individually.

You could do this more concisely, but this explicit example clarifies the process:

```js
// Declares and populates the Set
let sello = new Set();
sello.add( ["a", "c"] );
sello.add( ["a", "b"] );
sello.add( ["b", "c"] );

// Tests the `setHasArray` function
let result = setHasArray(sello, ["a", "b"]);
console.log(`result: ${result}`);

// Defines the `setHasArray` function
function setHasArray(theSet, arrayToMatch){

  // Creates a flag
  let isMatch = false;

  // Iterates through the Set
  for (let member of theSet){

    // Logs the Array we're about to compare elements of
    console.log("comparing:", member);

    // Makes sure this member is an Array before proceeding
    if(Array.isArray(member)){

      // Tentatively sets the flag to `true`
      isMatch = true;

      // Iterates through the Array, comparing each value
      arrayToMatch.forEach( (_, index) => {

        // Logs the comparison for the current value
        console.log(
          member[index]
          + (member[index] === arrayToMatch[index] ? " === " : " !== ")
          + arrayToMatch[index]
        );

        // Even one non-matching element means the Array doesn't match
        if(member[index] !== arrayToMatch[index]){
          console.log("Rats! Looked like a possible match there for a second.");
          isMatch = false;
        }
      });

      // Logs a successful match for the current member of the Set
      if(isMatch){
        console.log("Found a match!")

        // Stops checking Arrays lest the flag get reset and give us a false negative
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Returns our result
  return isMatch;
}
```

(See [`.forEach` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you're not familiar with this method.)