# How can I compare values of sets in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, set

I have a set for which I want to compare if it contains all the values or not.

```
const mySet = new Set([1,2,3,4,5])
```

This is what I want

```
const isAllActive = mySet.has(1) && mySet.has(2) && mySet.has(3) && mySet.has(4) && mySet.has(5);
```

am sure instead of this repetition there must be some other way to check that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [comparing ECMA6 sets for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128855/comparing-ecma6-sets-for-equality)

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5].every(mySet.has)` (note that this question ultimately isn't about sets or comparing them, it's about calling a function with a bunch of arguments and compiling the results; solutions are easier to find if you try to generalize the problem as much as possible)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the `every` array method to see if every element in the array you're testing is in the `Set`.

```js
const mySet = new Set([1,2,3,4,5]);
const hasAll = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].every(el => mySet.has(el));

console.log(hasAll);
```