# How can I verify if 2 JavaScript Objects have the same keys or not

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare 2 large JavaScript Objects with almost ~200 keys each, the keys are unordered, and have different values for each of the JavaScript Objects, but I only care about the keys if they both have the same set of keys that function would still return true even if they're in different order

I tried the following code but didn't work

```
var cp = function (nl,en) {
let x= Object.keys(nl);
let y= Object.keys(en);
for (xel in x){
    if (!y[xel]){
        console.log("missing key en ", xel);
    }
}}
```

Example:

```
{"key1": "val", "key2": "sdsfaf"}
{"Key2": "val", "key1": "vsdsdsd"}
This should return true
{"key1": "val", "key2": "sdsfaf"}
{"Key2": "val"}
This shouldn't
```

Comment: `Object.keys(arr)` and then go through them element by element.

Comment: JSON is a string format. Strings do not have keys.

Comment: list all the keys, sort the key lists, join sorted key lists each into a string, compare strings for equality ... `Object.keys(nl).sort().join(',') === Object.keys(en).sort().join(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab sets of the objects' keys with `new Set(Object.keys(a))` and `new Set(Object.keys(b))`.

Then compare them with eg. [comparing ECMA6 sets for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128855/comparing-ecma6-sets-for-equality)